# How to write a string into a xml file on c#?

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, xmltextwriter

I've created a xml file using c#.

```
XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("Product.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
writer.WriteStartDocument(true);
writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
writer.Indentation = 2;
```

Then, I create my string:

```
string stringXML = string.Empty;
stringXML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?><configurations xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=\"configurations.xsd\"><ProductsList><Product><ID>1</ID><Description>EPR</Description></Product></ProductsList></configurations>";
```

Then I want to write my `stringXML` into **Product.xml** file.

I've tried :

`System.IO.File.WriteAllText("Product.xml", stringXML);`

but it doesn't worked...

How can I do this?

Comment: Please increase your accept ratio , follow this http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 2):

Try it as

```
string s = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?><configurations xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=\"configurations.xsd\"><ProductsList><Product><ID>1</ID><Description>EPR</Description></Product></ProductsList></configurations>";
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(s);
xdoc.Save("Product.xml");
```

**Update**

```
string name = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
string s = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?><configurations xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=\"configurations.xsd\"><ProductsList><Product><ID>1</ID><Description>EPR</Description></Product></ProductsList></configurations>";
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(s);
xdoc.Save(name);
```

Since `saveFileDialog1` is your `SaveFileDialog`

Comment: Why you are using SaveFileDialog??just give the correct path in xdoc.Save and it will save file on that location..

Comment: The user must choose the path that they want, so i need to user saveFiledialog.

Comment: I update my code according to savefiledialog ..please check it out